# Fixing deprecated Sass color math operations

Tags: sass, postcss

I have just learned that it is no longer recommended to use math operators to compute colors in Sass stylesheets.  It so happens that I have a block of code that computes colors using addition, subtraction and multiplication, but it is causing `postcss` to produce deprecation warnings:

```
// Extension to Bootstrap's base colors
$gray-25: $gray-100 + ((#fff - $gray-100) / 4) * 3;
$gray-50: $gray-100 + ((#fff - $gray-100) / 4) * 2;
$gray-75: $gray-100 + ((#fff - $gray-100) / 4);
$gray-150: $gray-100 + (($gray-200 - $gray-100) / 2);
```

The actual warnings are:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 4 of /path/to/scss/_variables.scss:
The operation `#fff minus #f8f9fa` is deprecated and will be an error in future versions.
Consider using Sass's color functions instead.
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#other_color_functions
```

I had a look at the `color` [package](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color) but there does not seem to be an easy way of calculating a color based off another using simple math operators.

How would I go about fixing these deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A helpful soul pointed me to the `color.mix` function as a potential solution. Gave it a fresh look this morning and, after some fiddling, finally got it to work.  Ended up with the following:

```
$gray-25: mix($gray-100, #fff, 25%); // $gray-100 + ((#fff - $gray-100) / 4) * 3;
$gray-50: mix($gray-100, #fff, 50%); // $gray-100 + ((#fff - $gray-100) / 4) * 2;
$gray-75: mix($gray-100, #fff, 75%); // $gray-100 + ((#fff - $gray-100) / 4);
$gray-150: mix($gray-100, $gray-200, 50%); // $gray-100 + (($gray-200 - $gray-100) / 2);
```